# $z^4-16z^2=0$ in complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm a huge newbie with complex numbers, I ran this through WolframAlpha: $z^4-16z^2=0$
and got this

**Real Solutions** (I don't even know what that means)

$z=-4$, $z=0,z=4$

and **Complex Solutions** (again, don't know what that means)

$z = -2-2i\sqrt{3}$

$z = 2-2i\sqrt{3}$

$z = -2+2i\sqrt{3}$

$z = +2+2\sqrt{3}$

I tried using all the rules and everything I know to get to these kind of answers, but best I can get to is basically $z=\frac{16z^2}{z^3}$ in the expanded form of $z=16(a-ib)^2/(a+ib)^3$

I don't exactly know which solution I'm really looking for. Do I need to reach the same solution Wolfram does, or is expanding it enough?

The full question in case I misunderstood something:

Solve in $\mathbb{C}$ the equation: $z^4-16z^2=0$.
Show the solution in a $z=a+ib$ format.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Your equation is x^4-16*z^2=0, right? Your title is x^4-16z*^2=0.

Comment: No, @mathlove. The '*' stands for complex conjugation.

Comment: I've done this problem yesterday, coincidentally. (openu?). First, I noticed z=0 is a solution. now lets suppose z is not zero. multiplying the equation by z^2 seems to simplify the computation.

Comment: lol, yeah, i'm at openu, H.W is due today :P. but the equation is not x^4-16*z^2=0. it's z^4-16z*^2=0, notice both are Z and the Z on the right is a conjugate.

Comment: didn't see anything misleading, i don't know why u thought there is an x there.

Comment: @confidential: Not $x$. I meant $\times$.

Comment: "don't even know what that means" / "lol, yeah, i'm at openu, H.W is due today :P." If you are completely lost, this might indicate a gap between the teaching you are enlisted for and your current abilities. Getting full solutions from MSE will not alleviate this gap, only widen it.

Comment: I would approach this as follows. I first try to solve $w=z^2$. Because the conjugate of the square is the square of the conjugate, we have $w^2=16w^*$. By looking at absolute values we see that either $|w|=0$ or $|w|=16$. In the latter case we still have possibilities. I would try the polar form next. If $\varphi$ is the argument of $w$, then we must have $2\varphi=-\varphi+n\cdot2\pi$ for some integer $n$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @mathlove, i dun get it.

also, where did all the answers go?

i'm usually better than ok at math, though for some reason i find the books we use a bit confusing and very time consuming and is the exact opposite of summarized, right now i'm pressured by time, once i get some stuff out of the way i'll read some wikipedia on what i need to know.

Comment: can some admin restore all the deleted answers? 1 of them was just right.

Comment: I can see all three deleted answers, and all three of them were wrong.

Comment: And I would also recommend polar form for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z^4-16{z^*}^2=0\Rightarrow (z^2-4z^*)(4z^*+z^2)=0\Rightarrow z^2-4z^*=0\  \text{or}\ 4z^*+z^2=0$.

Then, you can solve them by using $z=a+bi\ (a,b\in\mathbb R)$.

From the first equation, you'll get $a^2-b^2-4a=0,2ab+4b=0$. From the second equation, you'll get $4a+a^2-b^2=0, -4b+2ab=0.$

1) $2ab+4b=0\Rightarrow 2b(a+2)=0\Rightarrow b=0\ \text{or}\ a=-2$.

The $b=0$ case leads $a^2-4a=0\Rightarrow a(a-4)=0\Rightarrow a=0\ \text{or}\ a=4.$

The $a=-2$ case leads $4-b^2+8=0\Rightarrow b^2=12\Rightarrow b=\pm 2\sqrt 3.$

As a result, we get $(a,b)=(0,0),(4,0),(-2,2\sqrt 3),(-2,-2\sqrt 3).$

Do you think you can do it for the second case in the same way?

Comment: trying to understand how u got from z2−4z∗=0 
to
a2−b2−4a=0

Comment: just put $z=a+bi$ into $z^2-4z^*=0$. Then, you'll get $(a^2-b^2-4a)+(2ab+4b)i=0$, right? Since $a,b\in\mathbb R$, we'll get the two.

Comment: i still don't see it though,
i only see how a^2-b^2-4a=-2abi-4bi

Comment: You need to know the following relation: If $p,q,r,s\in\mathbb R$ such that $p+qi=r+si$, then $p=r, q=s$. Our case is $(a^2-b^2-4a)+(2ab+4b)i=0=0+0i$, so?

Comment: uhhhhh, i get it now, but i'm still struggling with what to do next. 

for some reason an answer was here but is now deleted, i think that answer would've helped me.

Comment: @confidential: Is there anything that you can't understand?

Comment: got it now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- Every complex number $z$ can be written as $z=ru$ for some nonnegative real number $r$ and some complex number $u$ such that $|u|=1$. Show then that $u^*=1/u$.
- Write down the equation you want to solve in terms of $(r,u)$.
- This should imply that $r^4-16r^2=0$ (does it?) that is, $r=0$ or $r=4$.
- If $r=0$, then $z=0$.
- If $r=4$, rewrite the equation you want to solve in terms of $u$ only.
- This should get you 6 possible values of $u$. Multiplying these by $r=4$ yields the 6 nonzero solutions.